# Set field attributes on joomla 4 subform field

Tags: form, subfrom

Is it possible to set the field attributes on joomla 4 subform fields?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset
        name="userextendedprofile"
    >
        <field
            name="userextendedprofile"
            type="subform"
            label="Extended User Information"
            description="Subform Field Description"
            multiple="true"
            min="1"
            max="10"
            groupByFieldset="true"
            layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable"
            >
            <form>
                <fields name="uep">
                    <fieldset name="section1" label="User Profile">
                        <field
                            name="profile_firstName"
                            type="text"
                            label="PLG_ADVKONTENT_UEP_FIRST_NAME"
                            required="true"
                            filter="string"
                            labelclass="advkontentui-field-label"
                            maxlength="250"
                            class="advkontentui-field-value"
                        />
                    </fieldset>
                </fields>
            </form>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Usually you can load the fieldset then go through each field in the fieldset and use the $form->setFieldAttribute function. However in my onContentPrepareForm plugin function I've not found a way to set the field attribute on the subform fields. So in the example above, how can you set the attribute for the field profile_firstName?

**EDIT 2**
After further investigation, in my plugin I have been able to enter the subform and I can removeField/setFieldAttribute. By loading the outer fieldset, I was then able to load the subform and modify.

```
        $userextendedprofileFieldset = $form->getFieldset('userextendedprofile');
        $userextendedprofileForm = $userextendedprofileFieldset['jform_userextendedprofile'];
        $uepSubform = $userextendedprofileForm->loadSubForm();

        foreach ($fieldInfo as $field  => $group) {
            // Case using the advkontent users manager in admin
            if (\in_array($formName, ['com_advkontent.user', 'com_users.user', 'com_users.registration', 'com_users.profile'])) {
                if ($this->params->get('uep_required_' . $field, 1) == 0) {
                    $uepSubform->removeField($field, $group);
                } elseif ($this->params->get('uep_required_' . $field, 0) == 1) {
                    $uepSubform->setFieldAttribute($field, 'required', false, $group);
                } elseif ($this->params->get('uep_required_' . $field, 1) == 2) {
                    $uepSubform->setFieldAttribute($field, 'required', true, $group);
                }
            }
        }
```

If I inspect $uepSubform, the subform fields have either been remove or had their attributes modified according to the params. However when the parent form is displayed the changes in the subform are not reflected.
Is there a way to load subform back into the parent form?

Comment: caching problem?

Comment: Not a caching problem. I've traced the issue to the layouts/joomla/edit/fieldset.php file. It takes the parent fieldset then loads the child subform fields from the original xml file

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation into the issue, it would appear that with the current Joomla core coding of subforms, it is NOT possible to dynamically change the field properties of the fields in the child fieldset for existing data sets. If you add a new child fields set or the child fieldset doesn't have any data in it, then the fields in the child fieldset DO show the fields as modified in the plugin!!

Why this inconsistent difference in behaviour? The honest answer is I don't know. Both the functions loadSubForm() and loadSubFormData() and use the $this->formsource to define the fields in the child fieldset. In the case of loadSubForm(), when it loads $this->formsource, the modified XML elements are available, whereas when loadSubFormData() is called, the XML elements are from the original field file. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related is the issue that Subform fields do not respect the J5 "Toggle Inline Help" button which is bugging me somewhat.
Descriptions for subform fields are always shown irrespective of the toggle (it was the same in j3).

It seems there is some work to be done sorting out the subform field type.